# iOS Core Plot make x axis scrollable

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a question that is connected to implementation scroll in Core Plot graph object.

I use CPTGraphHostingView and CPTGraph for display my plots.

I have a problem when I have a lot of plots in my graph view, because they are stretched to the current rect.

I need to have ability make an interval (for example 50 points between each plot) and if total width of plots bigger than rect then make graph view scrollable.

I added this code for create range between to points

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
```

But this is just abstract range that will be recalculated for the current width of graph view. I want range that will be corresponded to the next data:

starts from: 0

end point:   xMax * 50 + offset (so for example xMax = 10 * 50 point + 15 point offset per each plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All plots are drawn in the plot area layer. After building the graph and adding it to the hosting view, call `-layoutIfNeeded` on it to update all of the graph layers. Use the size of the plot area layer to decide how many plot points you want visible. Set the length of the `xRange` to show that many points. Set `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` on the plot space to enable scrolling if needed.